# How to synonymize a database name?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, synonyms

Within **one** database instance, I need to restore a set databases into new names. The new names will be suffixed based on the development phases, like: _DEV and _QA. Where:

- DBApp_DEV shall access DBGen_DEV, and
- DBApp_QA shall access DBGen_QA.

From DBApp_DEV, I would do this in an SP:

```
select Col1 from DBGen_DEV.dbo.TableName
```

However, from DBApp_QA I would have do this in the same SP:

```
select Col1 from DBGen_QA.dbo.TableName
```

Now, how can I synonymize the database name in that SP?

Comment: Why not use different *server instances* for development and QA? That way you wouldn't have this problem at all.

Comment: There exists QA instance, but a bug needs to be resolved in Dev, hence the restore of QA into Dev without overwriting it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I managed to solve this by creating a Synonym in DBApp_DEV:

```
CREATE SYNONYM GenTableName FOR DBGen_DEV.dbo.TableName
```

And in DBApp_QA, the Synonym would be:

```
CREATE SYNONYM GenTableName FOR DBGen_QA.dbo.TableName
```

This way, I can maintain the exact same query in my SP that exists in both DBApp_* databases:

```
select Col1 from GenTableName
```